# How to randomly select rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I have two datasets with 20 rows each. I am looking
to randomly select 10 rows from each dataset following the
criteria below.

df1 group:

- 8 mammals
- 2 reptiles

df2 group:

- 4 mammals
- 2 birds
- 3 reptiles
- 1 fish

6 terrestrial and 4 aquatic ecosystems for both

```
df1.query("Class = Mammal").sample(n=8)

df1.query("Class = Reptile").sample(n=2)
```

I've seen solutions like this that should work, but I can't
figure out how to include the ecosystems requirement.
AKA I want 8 mammals and 2  reptiles selected from group 1,
ensuring that 6 of them come from terrestrial ecosystems and 4 from aquatic.
I think there should be a way to do this with a groupby function of
the two columns, but I haven't yet figured that out.

Sample data:

| Common name | Class | Ecosystem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lion | Mammal | Terrestrial |
| Humpback whale | Mammal | Aquatic |
| Crocodile | Reptile | Aquatic |

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in a clean way with just the built-in pandas functions like `groupby`.  That said, here's a solution using `random` and lists.

```
import random

animal_class = ["Mammal"] * 8 + ["Reptile"] * 2

ecosystem = ["Terrestrial"] * 6 + ["Aquatic"] * 4
random.shuffle(ecosystem)  # randomly shuffle ecosystem

df1_selected = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)
for i in range(10):
    df1_selected = df1_selected.append(
        df1.query(f"Class = {animal_class[i]} and Ecosystem = {ecosystem[i]}").sample(n=1)
    )
```

Just change the `animal_class` to do the same thing for df2.

Comment: For whatever reason, I receive a key error whenever I call the column value indirectly. I can write the query with Class == "Mammalia" and it returns the correct rows, but if call it using any form of animal_class[i] it says that "Mammalia" is not defined. I will need to investigate the syntax for queries a bit better, but this helps in conceptualizing what I want to do! Thanks :-)